# Understanding content provider and resolver

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I understand that a **Content Resolver** accepts requests from clients, and resolves these requests by directing them to the **Content Provider** with a distinct authority.

I was going through [vogellas tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.calendarapi/src/de/vogella/android/calendarapi/MyCalendarActivity.html), specifically the `queryCalendar` method, and I noticed that there are no calls for Content Provider. I only see code for **Content Resolver**:
 `ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();`

Why are there no calls for the **Content Provider**?

Comment: [Content Providers and Content Resolvers](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because the Content Provider is implemented by the Android system itself. If you look in the code, you'll see this bit:

```
Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
```

In the Android system, there is a Content Provider somewhere which is registered to handle Content Provider requests for that Uri.

In short: You'll only face Content Providers if you want to expose some data to another app (of course, no one is stopping you from using it within your app). Then, you'll need to implement one of your own (and expose it via a Uri). The Content Resolver is the thing that uses the Uri to talk to a Content Provider.

You can also look at [this Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo) to see how to define your own Content Provider.

Answer (score 0):

You see calls to ContentResolver because a ContentResolver is responsible for calling the methods of the ContentProvider and returning the data.

Written in the [official Android Guide on ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html),

> "When you want to access data in a content provider, you use the ContentResolver object in your application's Context to communicate with the provider as a client. The ContentResolver object communicates with the provider object, an instance of a class that implements ContentProvider. The provider object receives data requests from clients, performs the requested action, and returns the results."

If you want to learn Content Providers properly,

The following tutorials are the best tutorials online(along with official [Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)) for understanding how to implement Content Providers properly.

1. [Content Provider Basics](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-content-provider-basics/)
2. [How to Use Existing Content Providers in your app](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-using-content-providers/)
3. [How to write your own custom Content Providers](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)

These tutorials helped me get a solid understanding of Content Providers and I am not afraid of them anymore! :) Hope they help you too!

P.S. After you are done with Content Providers, you will probably want to use Loaders to load the data from the Content Providers into your UI. The [official Android tutorial on Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) is very good for that.